# JSF / Spring Security : view wrapper generates LinkageError

Tags: java, icefaces, apache-tomee

I'm having an issue with JSF rendering. Here's my setup:

- CentOS
- TomEE Plus 1.5.2
- Icefaces
- Spring Security 3

And my app is set up like this:

- /opt/tomee/lib/[all the normal TomEE jars]
- /opt/tomee/lib/[all the Spring Security jars]
- /opt/tomee/lib/icefaces.jar
- /opt/tomee/lib/icefaces-compat.jar
- /opt/tomee/lib/icepush.jar
- /opt/tomee/webapps/UI/index.xhtml
- /opt/tomee/webapps/UI/WEB-INF/lib/icefaces-ace.jar
- /opt/tomee/webapps/UI/[normal jsf 2 configuration]

There isn't anything obvious in the logs but when the JSF attempts to render I get the following error:

```
com/sun/crypto/provider/HmacCore

viewId=/index.xhtml
location=/opt/tomee/webapps/UI/index.xhtml
phaseId=RENDER_RESPONSE(6)

Caused by:
java.lang.LinkageError - com/sun/crypto/provider/HmacCore
at com.sun.crypto.provider.HmacSHA1.(DashA13*..)
```

The stack trace on the error page is massive, so I'm not going to dump a novel here, but here are the calls of note.

```
java.lang.LinkageError: com/sun/crypto/provider/HmacCore 
at com.sun.crypto.provider.HmacSHA1.(DashA13*..)
{...}
at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1221)
{...}
at org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.StateUtils.encrypt(StateUtils.java:328)
{...}
at org.icefaces.impl.renderkit.RenderWrapper.encodeEnd(RenderWrapper.java:53)
{...}
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
```

I dumped the contents of all the jars in tomee/lib but com.sun.crypto isn't anywhere that I can find in the web server. Apps that don't use Spring Security work just fine.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

OK. I got it to work so I'm going to be 'that guy' and answer my own question. I hope that it helps save someone else from the migraine it gave me. The problem went away after I did the following:

1. delete my war
2. let tomcat clean up the webapps dir
3. stop tomcat
4. delete the related directories from `work`
5. add the spring security taglibs jar to my app
6. remove the encoder declaration from my applicationSecurity.xml
7. rebuild the app
8. start tomcat
9. redeploy
10. drink heavily
11. profit

Step 10 wasn't actually a part of debugging process but I wouldn't have complained if it was.  Share and enjoy.